# Will Hawtio migrate away from AngularJS?

Tags: hawtio

Given that [long-term support for AngularJS is ending December 31, 2021](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status) are there plans for Hawtio to migrate to something else (e.g. Angular, Vue, React, etc.)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only the developers of Hawtio would know.

Comment: might i suggest you follow up on their github?

Comment: @DanielA.White, the [Hawtio website](https://hawt.io/community/) points users to Stack Overflow to ask questions saying, "We also keep an eye out on Stack Overflow for questions which makes it really easy to find answers to questions and commonly found problems. Though if you're running into an issue please use our issue tracker instead." I'm *not* running into an "issue." I just have a question. Therefore Stack Overflow would seem an appropriate place to ask this question. I would expect the developers to respond given what they say on the website.

Comment: Since I have not yet received an answer to this question I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2689) on Hawtio's GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered [here](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2689) on Hawtio's GitHub issue tracker:

> At this moment, there is no plan on migration or upgrade.

However, since that time the [Hawtio.next](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-next) repo was created and is being developed so it appears there will be a migration path at some point.